# Difference between "word for word" and "char for char" in Python

Tags: python, filtering

For a sentence called `txt` that I have split into `words`, I am trying to filter the words of 4+ characters into a list.

I've tried both `char for char in words if len(char) >= 4` as well as `word for word in words if len(word) >= 4`, and they give the same output. What's the difference between them? Which one should I use?

Comment: There’s no difference, it’s just a name. You can use `ogjebfprje for ogjebfprje in words:` and get the same result.

Comment: They are equivalent, you are merely using a different name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They give you the same output because you're actually asking python to do the same thing. Try doing:

`foo for foo in words if len(foo) >= 4`

In this case, `foo` is just the name of the variable - in the list comprehension it 'becomes' each word within the `words` list. The variable is also referenced in the `if` statement.

`char` and `word` are not special commands in this context - they are just variables named in a way that describes what they are.

This is the same with a variable declared in a loop:

```
for word in words:
  print(word)
```

or:

```
for foo in words:
  print(foo)
```

do the same thing - arguably the first is better because the name of the variable `word` helps give context to people reading the code.

Comment: Makes a lot more sense now that I know it's just a variable name

Answer (score 1):

In this context, 'char' and 'word' are just variable names. All the code is saying in either example is that you want to iterate a list called 'words', and you want to refer to the current item as 'word'/'char'. Either is acceptable, but you should read into list comprehension to understand more.

https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python